# Multiple loaders in MVP pattern in Android

Tags: android, mvp

Currently I am implementing `MVP` pattern for one of my module which has multiple `loaders` but I am facing problems in updating the Notification from the second loader call

Scenario:

Fragment invokes `Presenter.loadMethod()` initially to load the data in `gridview` and once the user clicks on individual item Presenter invokes `Presenter.Download()` method to download the file(not using `download manager`)

And I need to update the progress indication like whether the file is in download state or progress state but when the orientation is changed I am not able to update the notification bar when I use `InitLoader()`.

I tried with `restartLoader()` too but still facing the same problem.

Can anyone please explain what is the best approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep list of items being downloaded, save the list in `onSaveInstanceState()`. Start a separate `loader` for every download item.

In `onCreate()` method, you restore the items being downloaded and reconnect to `loaders` by calling `getLoaderManager().initLoader(itemId, null, this)`.

In `onLoadFinished()`, you should check if an item is downloaded successfully and change its state to "downloaded", then remove the item from the list.

Comment: where do you put initLoader and OnLoadFinished, on the Model?

Comment: @trocchietto. No, I put it in a presenter. You can look at it here https://github.com/Buckstabue/HeadHunterSearch/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/hh/headhuntersearch/async/loader/BaseAsyncLoader.java

Comment: I see @Buckstabue, I put it into the model to make the presenter lighter. The  class VacanciesPresenter.java is 350 lines, as far is testable, I guess should be right.Thanks

Comment: @trocchietto I think my presenter is big because I handle the view state over there. I could create some kind of an interactor that would handle view state and it would make it much lighter. Also I could create a facade over loaders api to handle error callbacks more concise like Rx

Comment: I see, makes perfectly sense, heres my upvote for your kindeness

Comment: @trocchietto How are you putting initLoader and onLoadFinished in Model without the context? Are you passing context from Presenter to Model?

Comment: @RisingUp, yes I am passing context from View to Presenter, and as you say from Presenter to Model, then from Model to Presenter, and finally from Presenter to View. It works, but still I gotta write test? Please tell me why you would eventually think is wrong. I cannot maintain the two Loader methods in the View, but also not in the Presenter, because the Presenter for definition should not have Android dependencies, so I moved to Model!

Comment: If you are passing context in Presenter, then you are introducing android dependencies in Presenter class same as putting loader would do. I was just thinking if there's better place for Loaders. But Google atleast thinks it should be in Presenter as per https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-loaders/ . Even I am figuring out  a better approach.

Comment: @RisingUp, nobody prevents you from creating a facade around Loaders. Anyway I don't see any disadvantage of putting android-specific classes into presenters.

Comment: @RisingUp is not google. But some google experts, I know that  repository really well and definetely I do not agree they put there, let's try to write them in github. Regarding the context if I pass view, or the context with dagger 2 I won't have dependencies right, especially if I am going to use interfaces?

Comment: @Buckstabue I think RisingUp is right.you should not put all these dependencies into the presenter. the view have to remain into the view!